# In Android, can you make gmail run an intent in a separate task?

Tags: android, process, gmail, intentfilter

We are writing an android app with an intent filter as below:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="www.appname.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.appname.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Android users with gmail who receive links to our app can choose our app as in the image below:

[image: gmail handles our app intent-filter]

However, when we look at recent apps it appears that our app is running inside the gmail process, which is not what we want.  Especially if the app is already running, we'd like for gmail to hand our running process the app intent for it to load in our app.  See how the gmail process has an embedded (separate instance) of the app running inside it, while the app is running in its own process:

[image: gmail app is running a second instance of our app to complete the intent]

Any advice on intent filters to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.  The android documentation is not at all helpful for this type of situation.

Comment: That screenshot has nothing to do with processes. It has everything to do with tasks: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for helping me get the nomenclature right, since I'm fairly new to Android.  Can the gmail intent be completed in another task, such as the already running task of the app?  It is expensive and potentially unstable to have multiple copies of the main activity running.

Comment: Try `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on your `<activity>` in the manifest.

Comment: This worked!  Can you please submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, an activity belongs to the task that started it. In many cases, that's the right answer.

If, however, you want control to go to an already-running copy of your activity, from perhaps another task, add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on your `<activity>` element in the manifest. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks):

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.

Comment: Very helpful! I had launch mode set to "singleTop" rather than "singleTask" myself. Before this, my app seemed to hang if I tried to open a file with it while an instance was already running. I think I must have previously had a false positive testing this by using the same external app multiple times in a row to launch mine.  The documentation says this mode is not generally recommended, as it differs from what users expect?  I don't follow that.  Who expects an app to open within another app rather than externally? Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html